# Change date format on datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i using this code to show a expiration date based on the select.

```
<script>    
$(function(){                  
    $("#date_picker").datepicker();
    $("#Plano_Id").change(function() {
        var offset = +$(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"), /* get days to add on date*/
        theDate = new Date();
        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + offset);         
        $("#date_picker").datepicker("setDate", theDate);
    });    
});        
</script>
```

But this returns the date in this format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I'm trying to show `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Use latest version of jQuery UI which has dateformat options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For setting the format for a specific date control

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

For setting it throughout your site/page, use

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
//Note:Call this before initializing any date pickers
```

Comment: To see a list of the available date formats performed by the formatDate function, check here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 1):

Use the dateFormat option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats